# Que es DSS y como utlizarlo?

Tags: asp.net

soy desarrollador .Net, pero actualmente necesito consumir un servicio por medio de DSS, las aplicaciones que lo consumen actualmente son en JAVA, pero realmente nose como hacerlo.

Este es el Servicio, alguien sabe como hacerlo?

https://centroderecursos.agesic.gub.uy/web/seguridad/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integraci%C3%B3n+con+Servicio+de+Firma+Digital

Saludos

Comment: Por lo que veo, se trata simplemente de un formato de XML...

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esta página](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/672063/Calling-a-service-with-oasis-header-in-Csharp) (en inglés) que te puede dar alguna indicación de como empezar.